# Kafka: assigning a name to an internal topic that is created after map and repartition does not seem to be possible

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

With this simple topology, stripped down for reproducing the issue:

```
public KStream<PropertyValueKey, PropertyValue> configureTopology(StreamsBuilder builder, Properties serdesProps) {
    KStream<PropertyValueKey, PropertyValue> propertyValues =
        builder.stream(kafkaProperties.getPropertyValuesTopicName());

    KStream<PropertyTypeKey, PropertyValueWithKey> propertyValuesByType =
        propertyValues.map((valueKey, value) -> KeyValue.pair(
                new PropertyTypeKey(valueKey.getProjectId(), valueKey.getPropertyTypeId()),
                new PropertyValueWithKey(valueKey, value)),
             Named.as("map1"))
            .repartition();

    return propertyValues;
}
```

I am seeing an internally created topic `appname-KSTREAM-REPARTITION-0000000002-repartition`

I can't seem to find a way to override this internal name. I have successfully overridden topic names in the past, when it came to stores, using `Materialized.as` as described in https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-topology-naming.html, but this doesn't work the same way as with this map function. Is there any way to do this? `Named.as` does not have the intended effect, or any effect that I can spot.

Thiss is with using the Kafka docker image `confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0` and the Java client 2.8.1, but upgrading to 3.1.0 did not matter.

Comment: I assume your input and output topics don't have matching partition counts? If they do, this topic shouldn't get created

Comment: @OneCricketeer all topics have 4 partitions, I wouldn't even know how to avoid that.

Comment: To configure internal topics, see - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#internal-topic-parameters

Comment: @OneCricketeer yeah we have a setting for the replication factor, but as far as I knew that applied to all topics.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I checked your link but that seems to be about prefixes. I would like to give a specific name to a certain topic. I have done this with KTables with `Materialized.as` before. This documentation comes closest: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-topology-naming.html, but the `Named.as` that I added has no effect.

Comment: If you just want to map data from one topic to another, that would be `inputStream.map( ... ).through("other-topic")` (or `to("output")`). I'm not sure I understand why you need `.repartition()`

Comment: `through()` is deprecated in favour of `repartition()`, see https://kafka.apache.org/28/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#through(java.lang.String). As for why it's needed exactly I'll need to get back on that.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps they renamed it to be more explicit about what that was doing... In any case, on the same page... Look at desctiption of `repartition​(Repartitioned<K,​V> repartitioned)`. Seems you want `Repartitioned.as`, otherwise, the suffix is fixed

Comment: Yes thanks, I just read that as well! That's the part I was missing here. And I think the difference is about that this is really marked as an internal topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was as easy as `.repartition(Repartitioned.as("property-values-by-subject-repartitioned"));`, unfortunately that wasn't mentioned in the docs but it was in the javadoc after some more searching.